# looking for practical solutions for optimizing text parsing speed with python

Tags: python, parsing, optimization, text-parsing

Set of lines need to be parsed with set of different named regexes.

Every line is passed through every regex until match is found. 
When match is found code should return/yield (named regex,value) pairs for each line.

Files are 2GB+ size so I am looking for some ideas for improving speed of my parsers.

Currently code is executed via python but that part is open to change. 
One option is to convert everything to C to get more speed from PCRE and faster(?) IO but that's a slow route that's hard to maintain in the future.

I'm looking for practical solutions like:

- converting parsers to some faster language
- moving to cython (?)
- splitting file in multiple chunks and running on top of few threads

Comment: Does not the very word 'parsing' imply that you *must not*  use regular expressions? They're not suitable for *parsing*  of any kind.

Comment: lets not be picky, i need problem to be solved, if you have better word to suggest for explaining my problem please suggest it.

Comment: I'm suggesting a better solution, not a better word. Use any proper parsers generator, write your own simple recursive descent parser, whatever else, but do not use regular expressions for parsing, they're not designed for this purpose. You can use them for lexing, if all your patterns share the same set of possible lexical tokens, this way you'll have a linear scanning speed.

Comment: I must admit you have a point there. Could you suggest some parser generator I could use with python / linux combination? After all point to this is to make all of this faster...

Comment: As you said, you might consider choosing another language - so, a good old combination of lex and yacc (both are lightning fast) could be an option. Otherwise, there are numerous options, including PLY, Yapps, and all the stuff from http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: @ SK-logic "Does not the very word 'parsing' imply that you must not use regular expressions? They're not suitable for parsing of any kind." -- that's patently and objectively wrong. Regular expressions, as the name implies, are perfect fit for parsing any regular grammar. DUH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first instance, I wouldn't worry about switching to another language. Alternative strategies are likely to yield greater benefits. The regexp engine used by python is written in C anyway (iirc).

1. 'Optimising' the regular expressions if probably your first task. How to do this is dependent on your text, and the expression. Have a [look](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python%20regular%20expression%20optimization) for articles and examples. @ThomasH also raises a good point.
2. The easiest way to optimise a regular expression is to remove it; See if there are any opportunities to switch to other tests such as `x in y` or `line.endswith()` etc.
3. Try running your code with [pypy](http://pypy.org/). It can yield performance gains without modifying code. In your case though gains may be insignificant as performance is bound to that of your regexps and file io.
4. Concurrent processing of the file across multiple threads/processes would *probably* be beneficial. I would suggest using one process to read the file and push lines to a queue from which multiple processes pull. There are numerous ways to do this. Take a look at http://effbot.org/zone/wide-finder.htm#a-multi-processor-python-solution

Answer (score 3):

One important point to speed up pattern matching in Python is to try to use a **single** regex. So rather than going through a list of regexes for each line of input, combine the regexes into one with `|` and then apply this regex once for each line:

```
reg = re.compile(r'''
    (?<patt1>foo)
    |(?<patt2>bar)
''', re.VERBOSE)

for line in lines:
    mo = reg.search(line)
    if mo:
        yield (mo.lastgroup(), mo.group(mo.lastgroup()))
```

Comment: this makes sense in series of few optimizations i can make, tnx

Answer (score 1):

First thing which comes in my mind is that you should use **re.compile()** to prepare all the regex. But I guess this is already done!

Another thing to consider may be hierarchical processing:

Depending on the type of regex you have they could be organized hierarchical. This way you could pre-filter the lines and only feed them into regex's you need to check.

For example if you search for a tag like "< body attr1 attr2>" in the regex it may help to string search that line for "body" in the line before checking if it really is a tag. You could also search for "<" before using the tag related regex.

It also may speed up processing if you combine multiple expressions into one and check the match. Like replacing a single checks for "{term1}" "{term2}" with "{(term1|term2)}".

Then you could try to filter which regex need to be checked by defining minimal line lenght they work on.

Simple stuff like this could speed up your application without switching to another language or cpu.

If possible you can also try to go multi-threading. Depending on the CPU's avail you could process every other line in two threads this may speed up processing considerably too.

Comment: re expression is automatically compiled by python internally and sub-sequentially used as such on any following call

Comment: hmm..tnx for info, i'll try timing my parser with compile() to see if it improves the situation..